# Como relacionar dois form fields no django?

Tags: banco-de-dados, django, python-requests, django-queryset

Boa tarde!
Sou novo no django e estou criando um sistema que servirá como uma planilha para auxiliar na análise de algumas demandas.

As demandas serão uma Certidão chamadas de CAT solicitadas por arquitetos. Ou seja, uma CAT será vinculada a apenas um arquiteto, mas um arquiteto poderá ter várias cats e eu gostaria de saber como salvar essa relação no banco de dados e como lê-la depois.

[image: O model do Arquiteto]

[image: O model da CAT]

[image: A view, que está basicamente recebendo os dados]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu quero fazer é que ao cadastrar a CAT e o profissional, um fique vinculado ao outro e eu possa depois pesquisar todas as CAT-As vinculadas a um profissional e possa verificar qual profissional vinculado a uma CAT. Mas usando apenas o foreignkey os dois não ficam vinculados, e no admin aparece uma lista de todos os profissionais cadastrados para eu vincular à CAT.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De fato, a forma correta de se implementar é utilizando uma *Foreign Key* (chave estrangeira) para o Arquiteto a partir da CAT. De acordo com o que você descreveu, os seus modelos estão corretos.

O que aparece pra você no Admin, com a lista do arquitetos para que você vincule à CAT, também está correto. Você deve escolher um dos arquitetos da lista e salvar a CAT, assim esse arquiteto está vinculado à CAT. Logo, **você já tem de forma automática qual arquiteto está vinculado à CAT em questão**.

Agora, para verificar todas as CATs que são vinculadas a um profissional, é um pouquinho mais complicado. Você precisa adicionar o método abaixo à classe `Arquiteto`:

```
def get_cats(self):
        return list(Cat.objects.filter(profissional_id=self.id))
```

Essa função retorna uma lista de todas as CATs vinculadas a um determinado arquiteto. Para isso, basta conhecer o ID do profissional em questão. Como esse é um método da própria classe `Arquiteto`, o ID nós já conhecemos: `self.id`.

O campo profissional_id é um campo criado automaticamente pelo Django na classe `Cat` devido ao uso da *Foreign Key*.

Se você lê um pouco de inglês, recomendo bastante a documentação oficial do Django sobre chaves estrangeiras: https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: Sua resposta me esclareceu muito, Wensiso. Obrigado! Esse sistema seria utilizado por analistas e a ideia seria que eles não precisassem utilizar o admin, mas que a vinculação fosse feita automaticamente. Isso seria possível? Se não for possível fazer pelo django, seria possível fazer utilizando outra tecnologia?